# Get list item total width

Tags: jquery, html

I have a bit of jQuery to get the size of a ul container, and automatically set the padding on each li to fill the space accordingly as each li is a different size. i have these variables set up to get the width of each li, but i can't work out how to get the total width of each li added together.

```
$('nav ul li').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        width = $this.outerWidth();

    $this.after($('<div>' + width + '</div>'));
});
```

The div after is just a test to check its getting the correct width.
How do i add up the total width of each li? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define your `width` variable outside the each function and update it each time it is called:

```
var width = 0;
$('nav ul li').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    width += $this.outerWidth();

    $this.after($('<div>' + width + '</div>'));
});
```

FYI, this works because of javascript closures. Take a look at this question for an explanation: [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: sorry? thanks for the response, but im not sure i understand how will defining the width variable outside the each function return the total sum of all list item widths?

Comment: `width` starts as 0, and in each iteration of the `each` function, the outer width of the next element will be added to `width` (notice the `+=`). After 'each' has iterated through all the elements, `width` will be the sum of all outer widths.

Comment: thank you, im so sorry i completely missed the += and as a result couldnt work out your responce. Thats spot on thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

In your case with is local variable.So the width will not update

```
var width  = 0;

$('nav ul li').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        width =width + $this.outerWidth();
       $this.after($('<div>' + width + '</div>'));   

});
```